# It is possible a two criteria filter in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart basic bar graphic where the category is the date, and each set is the amount sale per area (so I can let the user show only some areas, *as they need*). 
Now I need to stack each bar (cash, visa, mastecard, paypal, etc) and allow to show only some areas AND show only some payment modes. 
I mean, I need to filter in two distinct criterias to show/hide data: One per category and other per stack elements. 
Didnt find any documentation in highcharts about it.
Is that possible?

Thanks,

Comment: If your stacked items for cash, visa, mastercard, etc are `series` then you can filter them out via the `series.setVisible` property. http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the series setvisible is the filter Im currently using (on the category = date series). I need another more filter for each serie.

Comment: Please provide some live working demo of your chart.